# How do I get column names from a given MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

How do I get the column names of a table into a PHP array using the mysqli extension? I need to fetch the column names of any given table without fetching any data from the table.

Comment: How are you using `mysqli` currently?

Comment: Do you want to get the column names from a resultset or just the columns from a given table?

Comment: Columns from a given table

Answer (score 21):

The following code gets all column names from table `table_name`:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'USERNAME_HERE', 'PASSWORD_HERE', 'DATABASE_HERE');

$sql = 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM table_name';
$res = $mysqli->query($sql);

while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
    $columns[] = $row['Field'];
}
```

Since I have the columns `id` and `name` in my table, this is the result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => id
    [1] => name
)
```

---

If you want to get the columns from a resultset, it depends, but here is one way to do it:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'USERNAME_HERE', 'PASSWORD_HERE', 'DATABASE_HERE');

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table_name';
$res = $mysqli->query($sql);

$values = $res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$columns = array();

if(!empty($values)){
    $columns = array_keys($values[0]);
}
```

Example result for `$columns`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => id
    [1] => name
)
```

Example result for `$values`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Name 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Name 2
        )

)
```

Comment: When using either solutions the query returns a boolean not the column names.

Comment: @benjrei make sure the connection works... can you check for [errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)?

Answer (score 5):

You can use array_keys() to get all the keys of an array,

```
$myarray = array('key1' => 'a', 'key2' => 'b')
$x = array_keys($myarray);
```

The result you want can be obtained from $x

```
$x = array(0 => 'key1', 1 => 'key2');
```

Inorder to get the column names of a table,

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 1";
$ref = $result->query($sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ref);
$x = array_keys($row);
```

now $x array contains the column names of the table