# how to find a nth column of a mysql table

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to know how to find a nth column of a mysql table since I know that the query ->

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM TABLENAME
```

shows all the columns but I want to fetch only selected columns. Is there a way to pass all the column names in an array and then echo the nth column like:

```
echo $fields[n];
```

I saw that this query can also be done but I do not know how to get the column numbers from this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Information_Schema.Columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tablename AND ORDINAL_POSITION = nth but it
```

I am using mysqli db connection method.

Comment: What exactly does not work with that query? Using `SELECT COLUMN_NAME` (instead of `SELECT *`) this works perfectly

Comment: @Sinto nth column not nth row

Comment: You can execute a 'SHOW' query with mysqli just like you would execute a 'SELECT' query to get rows. You can get the output of the 'SHOW' in the same way as you get rows. See the second answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38553573/how-do-i-get-column-names-in-php-mysqli

Comment: $mysql = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM Information_Schema.Columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = employee AND ORDINAL_POSITION = 6";
$myquery = mysqli_query($con, $mysql);
$myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($myquery, MYSQL_ASSOC); => gives me error : mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given